# Set switch position to ON by first app launch using NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, xcode, switch-statement, default, nsuserdefaults

I have switches in my app that stores position by standardUserDefaults, but when app starts for first time all my switches are in OFF position. How can I set them to ON by default?

Save

```
NSUserDefaults *defs1 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defs1 setBool: blackSwitch.on forKey: @"blackKey"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Load

```
NSUserDefaults *defs1 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    blackSwitch.on = [defs1 boolForKey: @"blackKey"];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all

Do the following

```
NSUserDefaults *defs1 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
BOOL isOn = [defs1 boolForKey: @"blackKey"];
if(isOn) NSLog(@"isOn");
```

Second asure that blackSwitch is not nil

```
if(blackSwitch) NSLog(@"blackSwitch is not nil");
```

If blackswitch is nil, that means that you are still in early stage of view controller initialization, you should move the code that sets it on to viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear

For setting default values please use this code

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; 
NSNumber *testValue = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
NSDictionary *appDefaults = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
testValue, @"blackKey", nil];

[defaults registerDefaults:appDefaults]; 
[appDefaults release];
```

Comment: What do you mean by they work, does the 2 NSLog appeared in the console? and also please explain more about what do you mean by "first load"

Comment: If I delete the app and then build it again

Comment: OK i got your question, plesae check the edit i made to my answer

Comment: You should accept the answer and post another question, in order to keep question accurate :)

Comment: :) please edit your answer.. my key is "blackKey" not "blackSwitch". Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use the `NSUserDefaults` method `registerDefaults` to pass a default value of 'true' along with your @"blackKey" key.  This will ensure that @"blackKey" is set to ON until the user makes a change to it themselves.